# Grails pagination unable to maintain session

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a table with contents from database and a search button. It is having pagination. My Search field with name filterStatus. I need to put session on pagination. I have initially 15 pages with pagination and when I applied search it become 5 pages. The issue is when click paginate after search it is not maintaining session and returning back to 15 pages. The code as follows:

```
<g:form  contoller="adminMaster" onsubmit="return validateFields()">
           <g:hiddenField name="mysearch" value="mysearch"/>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <select class="top5" name="filterStatus" id="filterStatusId">
                            <option value="0" selected>Status</option>
                            <option value="true">Active</option>
                            <option value="false">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <div class="order_id_cancel top5">
<g:actionSubmit  class="btn btn-danger" value="Search" name="searchButton" id="searchButtonId" action="category"/>
</g:form>
```

.......   `<g:paginate  next="&raquo;" prev="&laquo;" controller="adminMaster" action="category" total="${dataCount}" />`

I have added a hidden filed there to maintain session. `<g:hiddenField name="mysearch" value="mysearch"/>`

My controller logic the follows:

```
def category = {
if(params.mysearch == null){
            println "inside ifffffffff......"
            params.filterStatus = session.formSession == null ? null : session.formSession.filterStatus
            params.mysearch = session.formSession == null ? null : session.formSession.mysearch
        }
        else{
            println "else..........."
            session.formSession = params

            params.max = params.mysearch != null ? null : params.max
            params.offset = params.mysearch != null ? null : params.offset
        }
```

}

Please help me. It is on grails.

Comment: You did not provide information that how you are fetching list from database. And also you do not need to save value in session for pagination.

Comment: @user1791574 values are saved session.formSession = params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
 if(params.mysearch){
     List<DomainName> domainInstanceList = DomainName.list(params)

  } else {
/*Do somthing to search your list. It would be better if you are using createCriteria*/
 }
Long totalCount = domainInstanceList.totalCount
render view: 'viewName', model:[clientInstanceList:clientInstanceList,domainInstanceCount: totalCount]
}
```

In gsp page:

```
/*Display your data here*/

<div class="custom-pagination">
    <g:paginate total="${domainInstanceCount ?: 0}" params="${params}"/>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: ty buddy. But what is the List<DomainName> domainInstanceList = DomainName.list(params)

Comment: its just a table name which you define in domain class. From where you are fetching list of object..